# Faster way than map() for big data (via stdin.readlines()) in python

Tags: python, dictionary, int, stdin

I've written a piece of code where i have to handle a lot of lines coming from stdin, split them, and then convert the values to integers (it's for a typical programming challenge).

My script needs ~20 sec for ~50,000 lines, but with cProfile i found out that all the map calls allready take ~8 seconds (i call split and map for every line, looks inefficient to me).

Here's what i do:

```
inp = [i[0:-1] for i in stdin.readlines()][1:]
inp = [map(int, i.split()) for i in inp]
```

What's the more pythonic way to do this?

Input looks like:

```
2        # number of testcases
2        # depth of following numeric triangle
1
1 2
3        # depth of next numeric triangle
1
1 2
1 2 3
```

thanks a lot for help!

Comment: Are you sure that you have profiled it correctly? On my fairly slow computer calling the code above on a 50,000 line file takes well under 3 seconds. The only thing I did differently was reading from a text file, not `stdin`.

Comment: well every line can have up to 100 values, and every value needs to be converted to int, maybe you've used a different input structure? i'm testing on a netbook which is also slow, but i get a timeout when i test my code at the online challenge's website.

Comment: I've tested it again with each line having between 50 and 100 values (rather than the 10 I'd previously done), and it was somewhat slower, but I would say still under 5 seconds.

Comment: Which version of Python are you using, and if it is Python 2.x, would it be possible for you to upgrade to 3.x?

Comment: 47870 times calling map on my sample input takes 6.484 seconds, calling split 47870 times takes 0.525 seconds. actually my script needs at all 20.050 seconds, so 6.484 seconds is way too much for map i think.

Comment: @sweeneyrod: python 2.7.3, updating is possible but i would like to know a solution for 2.x, i haven't played around with 3.x yet.

Comment: I would recommend that you use Python 3.x then, because `map` behaves lazily in 3.x, but not in 2.x. For me in 3.x, `list(map())` (the equivalent of `map` in 2.x) is almost 3 times slower than `map()` (which behaves differently).

Comment: Does using `imap` from itertools give any better performance?

Comment: imap returns a tuple, right? i need to manipulate the next line while processing the actual line later in code.

Comment: @sweeneyrod: i tested with python 3.x now, there is no significant difference in speed.

Comment: @jervis That's strange, there was a difference on my computer. Has anyone else tried this?

Answer (score 1):

Use numpy.loadtxt or numpy.genfromtxt.  That will load the numbers into an array far more quickly than you can load them with loops in Python, because the implementation is in a compiled language and it's highly optimized.

Comment: Why would the OP need to control the file format?  I pretty much assume it is line-oriented and space-delimited based on the code in the question.  NumPy can handle that.

Comment: Nevermind, I assumed the format expected by those functions is more restrictive. There's still the problem that the first line apparently needs to be ignored though.

Comment: No problem: just pass `skiprows=1` to `loadtxt()`.  And if your NumPy is very old and lacks that parameter, simply read the first line yourself and throw it away before calling loadtxt.  Couldn't be simpler.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to describe the input structure, first line is number of testcases, every testcase starts with one int and is followed by a triangle of numbers (1, 1 2, 1 2 3, ... that's why i have to split them)

Comment: @jervis: Please, show the sample input in the question!

Comment: Sadly, most of the programming competitions don't allow `numpy` :(